# Square root of an invertible complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an invertible $n\times n$ complex matrix.
Does there always exists an invertible complex matrix $B$ such that $A = B^2$ ?

My attempt :
Consider the Jordan form of $A$, say
$$J=
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 1 & \cdots \\
0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $A = Q^{-1}JQ$ for some $Q$ and $\lambda_i \neq 0 $ for all $i$ since $0\neq\operatorname{det}(A) = \operatorname{det}(J) = \Pi_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$. But I don't know how to construct such $B$ from this form.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: just notice that the Jordan form of the square of any invertible matrix in Jordan form is itself (with different eigenvalues)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does a complex matrix have a square root?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318694/when-does-a-complex-matrix-have-a-square-root)

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3958560/81360).

Comment: @Nicolas In brief, the answer is yes

Answer (score -1):

Use a binomial expansion if $A$ is "close" to the identity:
$$
         A^{1/2}=(I+(A-I))^{1/2}=...
$$
From Wikipedia

[image]